# Concat Columns produces NAN even though axis is the same for all datasets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am trying to concat columns from multiple dataframes.

```
`AUD = OHLC_AUDUSD['bid']['close'];`
`AUD = AUD.dropna()`
`CAD = OHLC_USDCAD['bid']['close'];`
`CAD = CAD.dropna()`

`print AUD`
```

> symbol  timestamp  AUDUSD  2015-01-05    0.8096
>           2015-01-06    0.8077
>           2015-01-07    0.8074
>           2015-01-08    0.8112
>           2015-01-09    0.8200 Name: close, dtype: float64

```
`print CAD`
```

> symbol  timestamp  USDCAD  2015-01-05    1.1756
>           2015-01-06    1.1838
>           2015-01-07    1.1818
>           2015-01-08    1.1826
>           2015-01-09    1.1864 Name: close, dtype: float64

```
`key=['AUD','CAD']`
`marketData = pd.concat([AUD,CAD], axis=1, keys=key)`

                      AUD     CAD
symbol timestamp                 
AUDUSD 2015-01-05  0.8096     NaN
       2015-01-06  0.8077     NaN
       2015-01-07  0.8074     NaN
       2015-01-08  0.8112     NaN
       2015-01-09  0.8200     NaN
USDCAD 2015-01-05     NaN  1.1756
       2015-01-06     NaN  1.1838
       2015-01-07     NaN  1.1818
       2015-01-08     NaN  1.1826
       2015-01-09     NaN  1.1864
```

What I would like to see is

```
              AUD     CAD
timestamp                 
2015-01-05  0.8096  1.1756
2015-01-06  0.8077  1.1838
2015-01-07  0.8074  1.1818
2015-01-08  0.8112  1.1826
2015-01-09  0.8200  1.1864
```

I haven't been able to figure this out!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a `MultiIndex`.  So the first corresponding elements don't both have the index `2015-01-05`, one has the index `(AUDUSD, 2015-01-05)` and the other has the index `(USDCAD, 2015-01-05)`.  These are considered different indexes.  You need to use `droplevel` to get rid of the `symbol` part of the index, leaving just the `timestamp`.

Alternatively, you can `unstack` the `symbol` index on the inputs before the `concat` to get the `symbol` as the column names.  Then, after the `concat`, you can overwrite the column names with `['AUD', 'CAD']`.